# Give opacity 0.5 to the 30% of scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a scrollable div for messages. I want opacity of 0.5 to the content at top 30% of scrollable div Like in image.
[image]. 
So while scrolling, whichever message comes on that div should have opacity 0.5. I have tried using an extra div background with linear gradient but the background color is clearly visible from my page's background color.Like this image [image]  So I just want to change the opacity of content but not the background of that region.
Thanks in advance.

```css
.message-scroller {
    height: 48vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position: relative;
    width: 55%;
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE 10+ */
    display: flex;
    //align-items: flex-end;
    background-color: black
  }


  .sc-message{
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
}





.single-message {
 
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 display: flex;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 //overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Barlow-SemiBold';
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #ffffff;
 line-height: 24px;

 .reserved{
  margin-right: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
 }
 
 .bot-img{
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  img{
   height: 15px;
   width: 20px;
  }
 }

 .user-img{
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  img{
   height: 20px;
   width: 15px;
  }
  // margin: auto;
  //align-items: flex-end;
 }
 .message{
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  max-width: 85%;
 }

 .show-more{
  color: #DF3535;
  font-size: 24px;
 }

 .arabic-message{
  text-align: right !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 2vw;

 }


 .show-more:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
}
img{
height: 25px;
width : 25px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="message-scroller">
       <div class="sc-message">
          <div class="single-message">
             <div class="bot-img">
                <div class="reserved"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="message">
                <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
                   <div>hello</div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="user-img"><img src="
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1G037foK0nwRpvvClvl9_WHA5bI_65goV
"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="single-message">
             <div class="bot-img"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pu1s3lGPPUmgiu6j0CSbkcZMVFA4c_YC
"></div>
             <div class="message">
                <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
                   <div>Hi, How can I help you today?</div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="user-img">
                <div class="reserved"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="single-message">
             <div class="bot-img">
                <div class="reserved"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="message">
                <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
                   <div>why?</div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="user-img"><img src="
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1G037foK0nwRpvvClvl9_WHA5bI_65goV
"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="single-message">
             <div class="bot-img"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pu1s3lGPPUmgiu6j0CSbkcZMVFA4c_YC
"></div>
             <div class="message">
                <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
                   <div>Sorry, I can't answer that at this moment.<br>Feel free to ask something else in the meantime.</div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="user-img">
                <div class="reserved"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="single-message">
             <div class="bot-img">
                <div class="reserved"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="message">
                <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
                   <div>ok</div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="user-img"><img src="
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1G037foK0nwRpvvClvl9_WHA5bI_65goV
"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="single-message">
             <div class="bot-img"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1pu1s3lGPPUmgiu6j0CSbkcZMVFA4c_YC
"></div>
             <div class="message">
                <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
                   <div>Okay, I can help you with queries related to HIV/AIDs</div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="user-img">
                <div class="reserved"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you fix your code snippet so that it works here? You're pointing to images with relative paths, so we can't see them.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and response. I have added images now you can check.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; no need: just to get scrollable content
}

.container:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30%;
 background: linear-gradient(#00000080, #00000000);
}

.content {
   padding-bottom: 100vh;// no need : to get scrolled content
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias amet animi culpa cupiditate, dicta dignissimos distinctio dolor doloribus dolorum enim ex explicabo, harum impedit inventore ipsa molestiae nesciunt nihil omnis pariatur perferendis perspiciatis porro, quae quaerat quisquam recusandae reprehenderit repudiandae sint sit tempore totam unde veritatis voluptas voluptates? Aliquid consequuntur cumque cupiditate deleniti doloremque error harum libero, nostrum obcaecati odio optio provident quas qui recusandae sapiente sequi voluptates? Culpa dolorem dolorum esse exercitationem illum maxime minus molestias nobis officia officiis porro quos, repellat soluta! A amet animi distinctio dolore enim error ex explicabo nostrum odio quia similique soluta, totam voluptas! At culpa error harum minus reiciendis ullam voluptatem. Corporis illo ipsa perspiciatis quasi ut. Asperiores autem delectus dignissimos dolorum eius explicabo, id, illo laudantium modi neque porro quaerat qui quibusdam quidem quisquam quos sequi similique suscipit tenetur, ullam velit veritatis vitae? Ab accusantium adipisci alias aperiam asperiores at atque blanditiis consequatur corporis debitis dignissimos distinctio dolore dolorum eaqu
  </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is it possible that only content should get 0.5 opacity, not the background? Because if I add background then it is visible to my Div.